# Remove last separator in View.ListView (F# Fabulous)

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms, f#, fabulous

I'm aware of the option to remove all separators

`View.ListView (separatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None)`

but is there an option to remove just the separator after the last item without building my own separators within the cells?

Comment: The best way to always do achieve this is use a box view to add a separator to your ListView, Then on your last item set the visibility flag to false.

Comment: Im not sure, if thats the same thought i had in mind with 'building my own separators'. If theres no other option i'd use BoxViews with height 1 in every cell except the last. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's the easiest way to do that

Comment: How could be the best way to know which is the last item? I added a bool property to my model called IsLastItem but personally I don't like this approach

Comment: I just checked if itemindex = list.length-1 in the view